# error: proxiesArrayList is not public in ServerListModel; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

proxiesArrayList was missing while I was adding that in response.
Its give me red color font and giving this error.

> error: proxiesArrayList is not public in ServerListModel; cannot be accessed from outside package

```
ProxyApiService apiService  = ((BrowserApp)getApplicationContext()).getService();
        Call<ServerListModel> serviceCall = apiService.listOfServers();
        serviceCall.enqueue(new Callback<ServerListModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerListModel> call, Response<ServerListModel> response) {
                ArrayList<Proxies> proxyArrayList = response.body().proxiesArrayList;
                Log.e(TAG,response.body()+"123");
            }

            @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerListModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
```

My ServiceModel Class

```
@Root(name = "serverlist")
public class ServerListModel {
    @ElementList(inline = true)
    ArrayList<Proxies> proxiesArrayList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
ArrayList<Proxies> proxiesArrayList;
```

To this:

```
public ArrayList<Proxies> proxiesArrayList;
```

Or even better, change it to this:

```
private ArrayList<Proxies> proxiesArrayList;
```

And then create a public getter and setter.

```
public void setProxies(ArrayList<Proxies> proxies){
     this.proxiesArrayList = proxies;
}

public ArrayList<Proxies> getProxies(){
     return this.proxiesArrayList;
}
```